# Ejecuto Código para enviar mensaje SMS sale este error

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, app

Este es mi error:

```
    {Java.Lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10249 does not have 
    android.permission.SEND_SMS.
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] 
    in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod 
    (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo 
    method, 
    Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in 
    <6cd960837cc24c26bab2a0a29b597627>:0 
    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod 
    (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, 
    Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in 
    <6cd960837cc24c26bab2a0a29b597627>:0 
    at Android.Telephony.SmsManager.SendTextMessage (System.String 
    destinationAddress, System.String scAddress, System.String text, 
    Android.App.PendingIntent sentIntent, Android.App.PendingIntent 
    deliveryIntent) [0x000ae] in <952e88faf9b94435845932f104eb293a>:0 
    at LoginSystem.Autorizacion.MBtnEnviar_Click (System.Object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e) [0x000c0] in C:\Users\Lenovo\documents\visual studio 
      2017\Projects\LoginSystem\LoginSystem\Autorizacion.cs:182 
    --- End of managed Java.Lang.SecurityException stack trace ---
     java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10249 does not have 
     android.permission.SEND_SMS.
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1555)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber(ISms.java:860)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:319)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:298)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5264)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21297)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
}
```

código clase:

```
  using System;
  using Android.App;
  using Android.OS;
  using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Java.IO;
using Android.Provider;
using System.IO;
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Linq;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Telephony;
using Android;

   namespace LoginSystem
 {
 public class OnAutorizacionEventArgs
{
    public string mTxtCedula;
    public string mTxtFirstName;
    public string mTxtFirst;
    public string mTxtEmail;
    public string mTxtCelular;
    public string mTxtTelefono;

    public string Cedula

    {
        get { return mTxtCedula; }
        set { mTxtCedula = value; }
    }
    public string Nombre

    {
        get { return mTxtFirstName; }
        set { mTxtFirstName = value; }
    }
    public string Apellido

    {
        get { return mTxtFirst; }
        set { mTxtFirst = value; }
    }

    public string Email

    {
        get { return mTxtEmail; }
        set { mTxtEmail = value; }
    }
    public string Celular

    {
        get { return mTxtCelular; }
        set { mTxtCelular = value; }
    }
    public string Telefono

    {
        get { return mTxtTelefono; }
        set { mTxtTelefono = value; }
    }


    public void Dialog_Autorizacion() { }
    public void SDialog_Autorizacion(string cedula, string nombre, string email, string telefono, string celular)

    {
        this.Cedula = celular;
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Celular = celular;
        this.Telefono = telefono;


    }
    public OnAutorizacionEventArgs(string cedula, string nombre, string email, string telefono, string celular)
    {
        this.Cedula = celular;
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Email = email;
        this.Celular = celular;
        this.Telefono = telefono;
    }
}
 public class Autorizacion : DialogFragment
{
    private string MSJTOMARgaleria = "Por favor reucuerda tomar primero la foto de la Autorizacion";
    private string MSJTEnvioExitoso = "Tu solicitud Esta En proceso, muy pronto te dare una respuesta";
    private EditText mTxtInstitucion;
    private string mTxtCedula;
    private string mTxtNombre;
    private EditText mTxtCiudad;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button Adjuntar;
    private Button Enviar;
    private View textView;
    System.String uris;
    private string mTxtApellido;

    public Autorizacion(string mTxtNombre, string mTxtCedula)
    {
        this.mTxtNombre = mTxtNombre;
        this.mTxtCedula = mTxtCedula;

    }

    public Autorizacion(string mTxtNombre, string mTxtApellido, string mTxtCedula) : this(mTxtNombre, mTxtCedula)
    {
        this.mTxtApellido = mTxtApellido;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        textView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Autorizaciones, container, false);
        textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoNombre).Text = mTxtNombre + mTxtApellido;
        textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCedula).Text = mTxtCedula;
        textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNota).Text = MSJTOMARgaleria;


        imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);

        Adjuntar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamara);
        Enviar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEnviar);
        Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;



        Adjuntar.Click += MBtnAdjuntar_Click;

        Enviar.Click += MBtnEnviar_Click;

        return textView;


    }
    private void MBtnAdjuntar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        var imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);


    }

    private void MBtnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (mTxtInstitucion.Text.Equals("")|| mTxtCiudad.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "has dejado Institución o Ciudad vacia", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }

        else
        {


            try
            {
                //Configurando el cliente SMTP
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com", "jwspvnzutniimvkm")
                };
                //Preparando archivo adjunto
                var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uris, "");
                var File = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                var path = Uri.FromFile(File);


                //Enviando correo
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com")
                };
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com"));
                mail.Subject = "Solicitud Autorizacion Medica " + mTxtNombre + " " + mTxtApellido + "" + mTxtCedula;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = "Hola Solicito por favor autorizar procedimiento, adjunto anexo solicitud Medica especificaciones el nombre de la Institución es  " + mTxtInstitucion.Text +
                " , ciudad " + mTxtCiudad.Text + " ,Nombre de usuario " + mTxtNombre + " " + mTxtApellido + " y Cedula " + mTxtCedula +
                " " + "Gracias por su atención"
                ;
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(File.Path));
                client.Send(mail);
                textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNota).Text = MSJTEnvioExitoso;
                Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCiudad).Text = "";
                textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoInstitucion).Text = "";

                SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("57301111111", null,
                "Hello from Xamarin.Android", null, null);
                var smsUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("smsto:57301111111");
                var smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto, smsUri);
                smsIntent.PutExtra("sms_body", "Hello from Xamarin.Android");
                StartActivity(smsIntent);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Mensaje Fallido"+ex, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }





    public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);
            imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);
            imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            uris = GetPathToImage(data.Data);
            Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            mTxtInstitucion = textView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAutoInstitucion);
            mTxtCiudad = textView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCiudad);
            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNota).Text = "";


        }
    }

    private string GetPathToImage(Uri uri )
    {
        string doc_id = "";
        using (var c1 = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            c1.MoveToFirst();
            System.String document_id = c1.GetString(0);
            doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }
        string path = null;

        string selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
        using (var cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
        {
            if (cursor == null) return path;
            var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
        }
        return path;
    }

    private void TextBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mTxtInstitucion.Text != String.Empty && mTxtCiudad.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            //Significa que hay texto en tus 3 txt
            Adjuntar.Enabled = true; //activas tu boton
        }
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;

    }

}
```

}

manifest.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  package="LoginSystem.LoginSystem" android:versionCode="1" 
 android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
<application android:label="Mi Asesor" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" 
android:theme="@drawable/ic_green_button"></application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

El logtrace detalla un error de permisos para enviar *SMS*, dependiendo del *API* usado hay diferencias en los requerimientos de permisos.

Por ejemplo:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero es mi primera App, por favor me puedes ayudar como implemento esa actividad

Comment: Depende de que versión de SDK estás usando, por la declaración de "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>" asumo que es mayor a la 23, pero ya con solo eso no es suficiente, debes realizar confirmaciones durante el runtime también. Puedes usar los metodos checkSelfPermission() and requestPermissions() para ayudarte.

Comment: hola cuando creo  el método "ContextCompat no existe en el contexto actual" y a"PackageManager no contiene definicion PERMISSION_GRANTED".. sabes si debo agregar alguna directiva en especial. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para Android 6.0 o mayor, se requiere garantizar el permiso  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>` de forma manual, no es suficiente agregarlo dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml.

Para esto puedes usar el siguiente método:

```
private void checkSMSStatePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!");
    }
}
```

Comment: hola cuando creo  el método "ContextCompat no existe en el contexto actual" y a"PackageManager no contiene definicion PERMISSION_GRANTED".. sabes si debo agregar alguna directiva en especial. gracias